# Check if port is open from the server itself

Tags: centos, port

I've a Centos 6.5 - Apache server. This server is in a private LAN (it has a private IP 10.x.x.x) and is linked to a domain name. If I test port 443 from webtools with the domain name, it seems that it's blocked, but I want to understand if it's blocked from a firewall outside the server or if it depends from the server configuration. Is there anyway I can check if the port is open for the server?

iptables firewall is empty.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply try to telnet from the server to itself.

So if you'd want to check if port 443 is responding, run:

```
telnet localhost 443
```

if the response is

```
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

then there's probably nothing listening on that port.

Comment: -bash: telnet: command not found Any alternative since telnet is not installed and I prefer to not install it for this single use?

Comment: You could try to use netstat instead, you won't be able to actually talk on the port, but it will list which ports are actively being listened on. Run: netstat -plnt

Comment: `tcp        0      0 :::443                      :::*                        LISTEN      25138/httpd` `tcp        0      0 :::80                       :::*                        LISTEN      25138/httpd` so the port is open on the server, and if the port seems to be closed from the webtools it's because it's closed on an external firewall, right?